# Check file size in shell and display file and path above a threshold

Tags: unix, shell

I am trying to check for files which are larger than a given threshold. I know that the 'du' comand gives me the output for each file/folder, but how to put that in a single line on shell (using awk with if clause?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` with `-size` parameter. Prepending `+` will yield all files of equal or greater size. For example to find all files of at least 10MB in current directory:

```
find . -size +10M
```